# Canvas showing only horizontally on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, canvas

I'm losing my mind on this... I'm working on a nice personal project, and I have a canvas on which I paint some graph... How, the issue is that that canvas works everywhere, even on IPhone, but only if it's horizontal... has anybody an Idea on what's going on?

the HTML is something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <canvas></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the canvas size are set using JS with the following script:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * canvasScale;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * canvasScale;
canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
```

am I missing something?

The project is uploaded here if you want to check the whole code:
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/AlbertoSinigaglia/force-graph/blob/main/force-graph-optimization.html

Comment: What's happening if your device is in portrait orientation? What's the value of `canvasScale`?

Comment: @obscure nothing is drawn... canvasScale is just a integer scalar constant, you can literally replace it with "2" for example

Comment: So you just can see the 'loss of the system' graph at the lower left?

Comment: @obscure exactly